# XSL modeler for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xslt, xslt-tools

I am looking for a good open source XSL modeler eclipse plugin. The graphical modeler should have a nice user interface for developing XSLs and should be functionally rich.
Can you please suggest ?

-Siddharth

Answer (score 0):

You should start by checking out Eclipse own XSL editor, its available from the webtools project; http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/sse/

Add the update site: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios/ and download it to try it out.